# Density of Borel set at 0

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The Lebesgue density theorem says that if $E$ is a Lebesgue measurable set, then the density of $E$ at almost every element of $E$ is 1 and the density of $E$ at almost every element not in $E$ is 0.

However, is it true that for each $t$ strictly between 0 and 1, there is a Borel set $E$ that has density $t$ at 0?

I have no idea how to construct such a set for a random value of $t$.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe the answer is yes, and I think you can do it with a sequence of disjoint intervals $\to 0.$

Comment: could you give me more hint on what intervals i should pick?

Comment: See [Lebesgue Density Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/77319/13130) *AND* [Lebesgue density strictly between 0 and 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/693508/13130) *AND* [Points of intermediate density for a measurable set](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1214591/13130) *AND* [Find $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that $\liminf_{\delta\to 0}\frac{m(E\cap(-\delta,\delta))}{2\delta}=\alpha$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1185250/13130) (and there probably are other similar questions here as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. In dimension $\geq 2$ this is trivial, so I assume we are looking at the real line.

Given an $n>0$ and $\alpha\in [0,1]$, put $U'_{n,\alpha}=(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n+1}+\alpha(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}))$ and $U_{n,\alpha}=U'_{n,\alpha}\cup -U'_{n,\alpha}$.

Put $U_\alpha=\bigcup_{n\geq 1} U_{n,\alpha}$. Then the density of $U_{n,\alpha}$ at $0$ is exactly $\alpha$. To see this, write $m(r)$ $$m(r):=\dfrac{\lambda(U_\alpha\cap (-r,r))}{2r}$$ and note that:

- if $r\in \left(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n+1}+\alpha(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})\right)$, then $m\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\leq m(r)\leq m\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\alpha(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})\right)$,
- if $r\in \left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\alpha(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}),\frac{1}{n}\right)$, then $m\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\leq m(r)\leq m\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\alpha(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})\right)$,
- $m\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\alpha$,
- $m\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\alpha(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})\right)\leq m\left({\frac{1}{n+1}}\right)+n\alpha(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})=\alpha+\frac{\alpha}{n+1}$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Let $I_n=(1/(n+1),1/n).$ Let $L_n$ be the length of $I_n.$ Out of $I_n$ we choose a subinterval

$$J_n = (1/(n+1),1/(n+1)+tL_n).$$

$J_n$ is a "$t$-bite" of $I_n.$ Set $E=\cup J_n.$ If I'm thinking about this right, we will have

$$\lim_{r\to 0^+} \frac{m((0,r)\cap E)}{r} = t.$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider a sequence of numbers $r_n \searrow 0$ such that $\frac{r_{n-1}}{r_n} \to 1$.  Let $\theta$ be a measure preserving map from $(0,r_1]$ to $\mathbb R^2$ that takes $(\pi r_{n}^2,\pi r_{n-1}^2] \subset \mathbb R$ to $\{x \in \mathbb R^2: r_n < |x| \le r_{n-1}\}$.  Then let $A$ be a 'piece of pie' centered at the origin in $\mathbb R^2$, with angle $\alpha$ at the corner.  Then $\theta^{-1}(A)$ will be a set with density $\alpha/(4\pi)$ at $0$.

This will give densities $0 \le t \le \frac12$.  To get $\frac12 < t \le 1$, simply add $(-\infty,0]$.

Comment: Is the existence of such a measure-preserving map obvious?

Comment: I don't think it is obvious, but probably not too difficult.  I do remember a result that says that all non-atomic separable measure spaces are measure equivalent to either $\mathbb R$ or $[0,a]$.

Comment: Let me rephrase that. Is proving the existence of such a map any easier than finding such a set?

Comment: All the examples pointed to by @Dave K. Renfro seemed quite difficult.  So I thought my example was worth mentioning.  It is at least intuitive.

Comment: But @zhw. has a simpler method.

Comment: Yeah, I was writing the same thing down.

Comment: @tomasz I would have got there eventually.